# Boostrap typehead (auto complete) ajax return multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i create auto complete using boostrap typhead

I want show when selected data from autocomplete, 
return 2 values and place to input box and hidden data

i found 2 problem

1. Data Autocomplete with double quotes
2. i can't place ID BIO in hidden type

this is my code

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "database.php";
$query = $_REQUEST['query'];
$result = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as total from biodata where NameBiodata LIKE '%".$query."%' "));
    if ($result->total > 0) {
        $data_tsk = mysqli_query($con,"select  IdBio,NameBiodatafrom biodata where NoUrut  NameBiodata LIKE '%".$query."%'");
        $data = array();
        while($tsk=mysqli_fetch_object($data_tsk)){ 
            array_push($data,array('label'=>$tsk->NameBiodata,'value'=>$tsk->IdBio));
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#name_biodata').typeahead({
          source: function (query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/auto_complete_biodata.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: 'query=' + $('#name_biodata').val(),
                success: function(data) {
                    var results = data.map(function(item) {
                        var someItem = { myname: item.label, myvalue: item.value};
                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(someItem.myname);  
                        return jsonString; // I don't know how to remove double qoutes
                        //return jsonString.replace(/\"/g, "");     // I try to remove double qoutes, but not selected
                    });
                    return process(results);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        updater: function(item) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(item);
            console.log(obj);  // i can't get Id BIO :(
            $("#IdBio").val(obj.value);
            return item;
        }
      });
```

**JSON**

```
[{"label":"Yeni Adelia Sofiyah als Selvi","value":"151"},{"label":"Yenni Ginting als Kak Yen","value":"276"},{"label":"Ria Wira","value":"572"}]
```

[image]

Help me thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double quotes are caused by `JSON.stringify`. This method is useful when you want send your JSON via HTTP request, echo your JSON as a string etc. In your case just use `var jsonString = someItem.myname;`.
2. Your code is generally wrong here. `source` should look like this

`source: [
      {name: "name", any: "value", you: "want"},
      {name: "name2", any: "value", you: "want"}
    ];`

`name` field is required. Without it typeahead won't work if you want to pass objects (that have name and other values) instead single values. In your case you get

```
source: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'etc'];
```

So you should do something like that

```
  source: function (query, process) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/auto_complete_biodata.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: 'query=' + $('#name_biodata').val(),
        success: function(data) {
            var results = data.map(function(item) {
                var someItem = { name: item.label, myvalue: item.value}; 
                return someItem;
            });
            return process(results);
        }
    });
},
```

Now you will get

```
[
  {name: 'name_from_label', myvalue: 'your_value'}
]
```

That's all.

Comment: I'm already impelemented. But cannot select. in error console show
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah that's because you're trying to parse JSON object to JSON in ```updater``` method. You don't need to create `obj` var, just use `item`.

Comment: It's work, when already comment     // minLength: 1,
        // updater: function(item) {
        //     var obj = JSON.parse(item);
        //     console.log(obj);
        //     return item;
        // }

So how to place >> $("#IdBio").val(obj.value);

Comment: ok work. im fix like this. 
        minLength: 1,
        updater: function(item) {
            $('#IdBio').val(item.myvalue);
            return item;
        }

Thank's Wolen